# How change git visibility after clone project

Tags: git

I have done `git clone` from remote repository.

When project has been opened all files was marked as unresolved (red color).
I try to change branch but it need for permission, after changes **config** file in **.git** directory, the line

`worktree=<path to .git>`

was added, check out have done as well, but all files changed as new (blue color).

I tried to do `git revert` on some file and this file reverted to normal state (changed only color).
Also the action git pull writes **all files updated**.

What need to do, that all files have state as 'after git'(not unresolved, new or changed)?.
I think apply revert action to all files on the project isn't good solution.

Comment: "red color"? What software are you using?

Comment: ide: intellije idea

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it was red, but rather brown: see "[IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 Help: File Status Highlights](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/file-status-highlights.html)"

> **Brown**     **Unknown   File**: exists locally, but is not in the  repository, and is not scheduled for adding.

[image]

> **Red**   **Merged with conflicts**   During the last update, file was merged with conflicts.

If the working tree is correctly set, and all files appears to be "modified" (Blue), it could be because of an automatic eol (end of line) conversion.

Check in the Git configuration that core.autocrlf is set to false.

As it turned out, the worktree was incorrectly set: the [OP JAVAvladuxa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067277/javavladuxa) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931549/how-change-git-visibility-after-clone-project/39931684#comment67152202_39931684):

> I have changed worktree value for global git, and it solved my problem.

Comment: I changed core.autocrlf for local git to false, and update project in idea, and files still have state 'modified without checkout'. I work in Ubuntu.

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa can you try a git status in command line (in your repo)?

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa what find of modification? (git diff)

Comment: modified files in .idea folder

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa I mean: what typical modification does a git diff show?

Comment: sorry, i have changed worktree value for global git, and it solved my problem thank you

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.